# Xamrin Forms : Swipe to delete(gesture) in ListView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, swipe-gesture, xamarin.forms

I want to implement the swipe to delete functionality in  Xamrin Forms, for which i have tried the following.

1. Wrote a custom renderer for the list view and in the "OnElementChanged" of the renderer am able to access the binded command to the "CustomListView" and am able to add this command to the Swipe Gesture as added below.

   ```
      swipeGestureRecognizer = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer (() => {
           if (command == null) {
               Console.WriteLine ("No command set");
               return;}

           command.Execute (null);
       });
   ```

However i am having trouble in accessing the specific row(swiped row), so that i could make a button visible/hidden on the swiped row in the list view. Please could you recommend a way to implement the same?

Comment: I would add the gesture to the ItemTemplate or UITableCell instead.

Comment: Have u achieved this for android as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        var swipeDelegate = new SwipeRecogniserDelegate ();
        swipeGestureRecognizer = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left,
            Delegate = swipeDelegate
        };
        swipeGestureRecognizer.AddTarget (o => {
            var startPoint = swipeDelegate.GetStartPoint ();
            Console.WriteLine (startPoint);
            var indexPath = this.Control.IndexPathForRowAtPoint(startPoint);
            if(listView.SwipeCommand != null) {
                listView.SwipeCommand.Execute(indexPath.Row);
            }
        });
        this.Control.AddGestureRecognizer (swipeGestureRecognizer);
        this.listView = (SwipableListView)this.Element;
    }
```

The key is `SwipeRecogniserDelegate`. its implemented like so:

```
public class SwipeRecogniserDelegate : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
{
    PointF startPoint;

    public override bool ShouldReceiveTouch (UIGestureRecognizer recognizer, UITouch touch)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool ShouldBegin (UIGestureRecognizer recognizer)
    {
        var swipeGesture = ((UISwipeGestureRecognizer)recognizer);
        this.startPoint = swipeGesture.LocationOfTouch (0, swipeGesture.View);
        return true;
    }

    public PointF GetStartPoint ()
    {
        return startPoint;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Swipe to delete is now built into Xamarin Froms ListViews using a ContextAction.  Here is the most basic tutorial of how to do it. It is very easy to implement.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/listview/

Comment: The xamarin forms implementation does cover the most basic use case.
FYI: unfortunately you can't swipe right with the xamarin forms implementation though. You're also stuck with the most basic menu items that you can't really customise at all (e.g. select a different font for the text), which means you'll need to start looking at custom renderers almost immediately.

Comment: Yeah I have found documentation for this in particular to be very lacking.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with the new Xamarin.Forms
[SwipeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/swipeview)

Pass the current row into the CommandParameter, and use it in the event handler.

FYI: For some reason the SwipeView has a default BackgroundColor of white, which you can override with something else to match your theme.

Xaml:

```
            <ListView Margin="-20,0,0,0" x:Name="photosListView" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SeparatorColor="Gray" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="true"  SeparatorVisibility="Default" Background="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <SwipeView BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}" >
                                <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                    <SwipeItems>
                                        <SwipeItem Text="Delete" BackgroundColor="LightPink" Clicked="OnDeleteRow" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                    </SwipeItems>
                                </SwipeView.RightItems>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <CheckBox IsVisible="{Binding SelectEnabled}" Color="{StaticResource White}" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" Margin="20,0,-15,0"  CheckedChanged="OnItemCheckedChanged" />
                                        <Grid WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="50">
                                            <Grid.Margin>
                                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Android="15,0,0,0" iOS="10,0,0,0" />
                                            </Grid.Margin>
                                            <Image Aspect="AspectFill"  Source="{Binding ThumbImageSource}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackLayout>

                                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Spacing="0" Padding="0" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Photo.Description}" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColour}" FontSize="16" FontAttributes="Bold"  />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding DateTakenString}" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColour}" FontSize="14" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </SwipeView>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
```

cs:

```
    public async void OnDeleteRow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (await GetDeleteRowConfirmationFromUser())
        {
            SwipeItem si = sender as SwipeItem;
            PhotoListItem itemToDelete = si.CommandParameter as PhotoListItem;
            LocalDatabaseService db = new LocalDatabaseService();
            db.DeletePhoto(itemToDelete.Photo);
            _listItems.Remove(itemToDelete);
        }
    }
```